# What is the distribution of the number of occurrences of a given integer, in repeated samples drawn from Uniform Integer [1, N] distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution

If I draw M repeated samples from Uniform Integer Distribution on [1,N], what will be the distribution of the number of times a given integer chosen among the integers 1,2,...,N appears in my M samples?

For concreteness, lets say that I draw repeatedly 100 times from Uniform Integer [1,5] distribution. What then will be the distribution of the number of times the integer 3 appears in my 100 samples?

Answer (score 4):

In a *single* draw, your chosen integer will be drawn with probability $\frac{1}{N}$. Since you draw with replacement, the total number of such successes is [binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $M$ and $p=\frac{1}{N}$.